# Website not covering full screen in portrait view

Tags: css, responsive-design, mobile-website

I have designed responsive **website** viz working perfectly in laptop and *landscape* view of Tab and mobile.

When I've checked that in *portrait* view body tag is not covering full screen, A white vertical band appear in right side of the screen.

Landscape view:

[image]

No error... Working Perfectly...

Portrait View:

[image]

Body is not covering full page....

Body tag **CSS**:

```
 body{
   font-family: 'Raleway','Arial Narrow', serif;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin:0 !important ;
 padding:0 !important
    }
```

Comment: Checked and its working fine for me? no white space on the right?

Comment: @RachelGallen `body` doesn't have native padding.

Comment: @Aaron In which device you device... Its not working for me in mobile portrait view...

Comment: @Rachel thanks for ur suggestion but it didnt work...

Comment: @MonickaAkilan Ive set my resolution to 384x640 and am not seeing any white space

Comment: @Aaron it didnt works for me... can you please share that screenshot if possible...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88686/discussion-between-monicka-akilan-and-aaron).

Comment: Can you share a link of website to identify the issue?

Comment: your class `.fs-container` havng `box-sizing: content-box;` viz causing the issue which you've used for that folded view, and its not only for *portrait* its for *landscape* as well.

Comment: @vivek Can you please guide me to change that css.... No box-sizing value solve that issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `box-sizing: content-box;` for the class `fs-container` viz causing the issue, its your `<body>` **is** covering your full website but due that property on class there is *white-space*.

I've used this **CSS**:

```
       @media screen and (max-width: 570px) {

          .fs-container {
              position: relative;
              width: 100%;
              padding: 0 20%;
              max-width: 100%;
              left: 35px;
              -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
               box-sizing: border-box;
           }

            .fs-block {
               width: 100%;
            }

      }

     @media screen and (max-width: 380px) {

           .fs-container {
              padding: 0 15%;
           }

     }
```

on particular *media-query*, please try this, it will do the trick for you.

Comment: Soooper Dooper like for your answer.... Thanks for your interest.... Now its working fine.....

Comment: @MonickaAkilan its glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a universal selector for `margin` and `padding`.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Sometimes it will create some problems.

Comment: then you have to check your website's Portrait View in inspect element mode in your browser may be this will help you to find out this white space.

Comment: Ya i checked in that only.... Simple body tag covering that un white space.... no padding or margin present... Thats why i could not figure out the issue....

Comment: upto my point of view the error was in the "fs-container" class's min or max width of section tag in the body. by changing this i hope your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I check this in my Developer Tools and everything worked fine.

Maybe the problem is your code you posted:

```
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin:0 !important ;
 padding:0 !important
```

Please check your semicolon:

```
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0 !important;
```